# SQL Select up to a certain sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been trying to figure out a way to write a SQL script to select a given sum, and would appreciate any ideas given to do so.

I am trying to do a stock valuation based on the dates of goods received. At month-end closing, the value of my stocks remaining in the warehouse would be a specified sum of the last received goods.

The below query is done by a couple of unions but reduces to:

```
SELECT DATE, W1 FROM Table
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

Query result:

```
Row     DATE                W1      
1       2019-02-28 00:00:00 13250   
2       2019-02-28 00:00:00 42610   
3       2019-02-28 00:00:00 41170   
4       2019-02-28 00:00:00 13180   
5       2019-02-28 00:00:00 20860   
6       2019-02-28 00:00:00 19870   
7       2019-02-28 00:00:00 37780   
8       2019-02-28 00:00:00 47210   
9       2019-02-28 00:00:00 32000   
10      2019-02-28 00:00:00 41930
```

I have thought about solving this issue by calculating a cumulative sum as follows:

```
Row     DATE                W1      Cumulative Sum
1       2019-02-28 00:00:00 13250   13250         
2       2019-02-28 00:00:00 42610   55860         
3       2019-02-28 00:00:00 41170   97030         
4       2019-02-28 00:00:00 13180   110210        
5       2019-02-28 00:00:00 20860   131070        
6       2019-02-28 00:00:00 19870   150940  
7       2019-02-28 00:00:00 37780   188720  
8       2019-02-28 00:00:00 47210   235930  
9       2019-02-28 00:00:00 32000   267930  
10      2019-02-28 00:00:00 41930   309860
```

However, I am stuck when figuring out a way to use a parameter to return only the rows of interest.

For example, if a parameter was specified as '120000', it would return the rows where the cumulative sum is exactly 120000.

```
Row     DATE                W1      Cumulative Sum  W1_Select
1       2019-02-28 00:00:00 13250   13250           13250
2       2019-02-28 00:00:00 42610   55860           42610
3       2019-02-28 00:00:00 41170   97030           41170
4       2019-02-28 00:00:00 13180   110210          13180
5       2019-02-28 00:00:00 20860   131070          9790
                                                    ----------
                                    Total           120000
```

Comment: I am using MSSQL 2008 R2 Express

Answer (score 0):

This just requires some arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when running_sum < @threshold then w1
             else @threshold - w1
        end)
from (select date, w1, sum(w1) over (order by date) as running_sum
      from t
     ) t
where running_sum - w1 < @threshold;
```

Actually, in your case, the dates are all the same.  That is a bit counter-intuitive, but you need to use the row for this to work:

```
select t.*,
       (case when running_sum < @threshold then w1
             else @threshold - w1
        end)
from (select date, w1, sum(w1) over (order by row) as running_sum
      from t
     ) t
where running_sum - w1 < @threshold;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8293d9ebda091f718ab5bce068e58e9f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon, I appreciate your help and will give it a try.
The actual dataset would have a range of dates.

Comment: @yongsheng . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have another question, you should ask a *new* question.  Note that this includes a SQL Fiddle **with your example data**, and it works.